# Kendo. How can I access the nested grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I use hierarhical Kendo Grid. 
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

Nested grids are created with such function:

```
function detailInit(e) {
$("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    name: "nestedGrid",
    dataSource: {
        ...
    },
    columns: [
        ...
}).addClass("nested-grid-class");
```

How can I access the grid in another function? For example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
      var grid = $(".nested-grid-class").data("kendoGrid");
      alert('grid =  ' + grid);                      // grid = undefined
      var grid = $("nestedGrid").data("kendoGrid");
      alert('grid =  ' + grid);                      // grid = null
      var grid = $("#nestedGrid").data("kendoGrid");
      alert('grid =  ' + grid);                      // grid = null
     var grid = $("[name='nestedGrid']").data("kendoGrid");
      alert('grid =  ' + grid);                      // grid = null
});
```

The way proposed by Sandman doesn't work too

```
var grid = $("#MainGrid").data("kendoGrid");
alert('MainGrid = ' + grid);         // ok
var parentRows = grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row");
alert('parentRows = ' + parentRows);        // ok

parentRows.each(function (e) {
    var row = $(this).next("tr");
    alert('row = ' + row);        // ok
    if (row.hasClass("k-detail-row")) {
        var nestedGrid = row.find(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
        alert('nestedGrid = ' + nestedGrid);        // undefined
        var nestedGrid1 = row.find(".nested-grid-class").data("kendoGrid");
        alert('nestedGrid1 = ' + nestedGrid1);        // undefined        
    }
});
```

Comment: When you actually want the nested grid?

Comment: What do you mean "when"?

Comment: What does `row` contain? Use your console window to [debug your Javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript)

Comment: See my edit for an example

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the nested grid for each row of the grid you could use the following:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var parentRows = grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row");
```

This should get you all `parent` rows.  Then you can iterate over these using `.each` in order to access the child grid within:

```
parentRows.each(function(e){
   var row = $(this).next("tr");
   if(row.hasClass("k-detail-row")){
      var nestedGrid = row.find(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
      // EDIT: In your case, you may need to get by class - UNTESTED
      // var row.find(".nested-grid-class").data("kendoGrid");
      //access nested grid data here          
   }
});
```

**EDIT**

I have prepared an [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/AdoGuW) based on the initial Dojo you sent through in your question which logs each *initialised* nested grid in the console. (NOTE: Both '`.k-grid`' and '`.nested-grid-class`' were valid selectors).

The issue for you is that only the first row was initialised in the `dataBound` event therefore meaning it was the only row to have a nested grid created. I have extended the example further so that all nested grids will be initialised during the `dataBound` function (`this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));`).

If you examine the console now, you will see the list of 6 parent rows, and 6 lists containing each nested grid datasource.

[image: Console containing output]

Comment: How does it not work? Is there an error in the console window/what is in `nestedGrid` variable?  Additionally you may find debugging with the console window to be quite helpful instead of alerting variables..

Comment: I can't understand how I can write some code in comments so I added the information about your method to the starting post.